# Problem with Yii 2 pagination in a ListView

Tags: php, pagination, yii2

I've got a problem with Yii 2 pagination. My case is a little bit strange. What I'm trying to do is a ListView with some ChartJS inside. The problem is that when I click on page button the whole page is reloaded. The ListView is inside an accordion component, and maybe this is the problem that I'm not able to solve. Here is my code:

In SiteController:

```
    $usercenters = Yii::$app->mycomponent->getCenIds();
                            $query = new Query;
                            $query->select('distinct(center.id)')
                                ->from('campaign_center')
                                ->innerjoin('center', 'center.id = campaign_center.center_id')
                                ->where("campaign_center.campaign_id = " . $_POST['campaignid'])
                                ->andWhere("campaign_center.center_id in(" . $usercenters . ")");
                            $centers = $query->all();
                            $page = $_POST['page'];
                            $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                                'allModels' => $centers,
                                'pagination' => [
                                    'pageSize' => 3,
                                    'page' => $page,
                                    'totalCount' => $query->count()
                                ],
                                'sort' => [
                                    'attributes' => ['id'],
                                ],
                            ]);
                            return $this->renderAjax('_campaigntypeslevel_list', ['tipojerarquia' => $_POST['tipojerarquia'], 'origincampaigntype' => $_POST['origincampaigntype'], 'campaignid' => $_POST['campaignid'],'provider'=>$provider, 'centers'=>$centers,'usercenters'=>$usercenters]);
```

First view (_campaigntypeslevel_list):

```
    Pjax::begin(['timeout' => 10000, 'clientOptions' => ['container' => 'pjax-container']]);
    echo ListView::widget([
         'id'=>'centerslistview',
         'dataProvider' => $provider,
         'layout' => '<div>{summary}</div><div>{pager}</div><div>{items}</div>',
         'itemView'     =>'_centers',
         'viewParams' => ['tipojerarquia' => $tipojerarquia, 
         'center' => $centermodel->id, 'campaign' => $campaignid, 
         'origincampaigntype' => $origincampaigntype, 'dataPie' => 
         $dataPie, 'dataBox' => $dataBox, '$dataPieLastYear' => 
         $dataPieLastYear, 'dataBoxLastYear'=>$dataBoxLastYear,'centers'=>$centers,'usercenters'=>$usercenters],
 ]);
    Pjax::end();
```

Finally in _centers view:

```
    <?php
   use app\models\Campaign;
   use app\models\Center;

   $campaignmodel = Campaign::findOne($campaign);
   $dataPie = Yii::$app->chartfunctions->getHomeNPSData(Yii::$app->user->identity, NULL, $model['id'], NULL, $campaignmodel->id, NULL, NULL);
   $dataBox = Yii::$app->chartfunctions->getHomeNPSDataByMonth(Yii::$app->user->identity, NULL, $model['id'], NULL, $campaignmodel->id, NULL, NULL);
   $dataPieLastYear = Yii::$app->chartfunctions->getHomeNPSData(Yii::$app->user->identity, NULL, $model['id'], NULL, $campaignmodel->id, NULL, date('Y'));
   $dataBoxLastYear = Yii::$app->chartfunctions->getHomeNPSDataByMonth(Yii::$app->user->identity, NULL, $model['id'], NULL, $campaignmodel->id, NULL, date('Y'));
   echo \Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_boxcontent', ['tipojerarquia' => $tipojerarquia, 'center' => $model['id'], 'campaign' => $campaignmodel->id, 'origincampaigntype' => $origincampaigntype, 'dataPie' => $dataPie, 'dataBox' => $dataBox, '$dataPieLastYear' => $dataPieLastYear, 'dataBoxLastYear' => $dataBoxLastYear],false,true);

   ?>
```

Maybe renders are not right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from the pajax.

> PJAX has timeout option. If PJAX not obtain AJAX response during this
>   timeout, it will perform full page reload.

Check the answers in this question, its the same problem, maybe you will find the light:

[How to refresh pjax listview in yii2? It reloads the entire page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563401/how-to-refresh-pjax-listview-in-yii2-it-reloads-the-entire-page)